# bash escape exclamation character inside variable with backtick

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, mysql

I have this bash script name test.sh and located in /tmp:

```
source $HOME/.backmeuprc
databases=`mysql -h$DBHOST -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`
```

the .backmeuprc file is located in `/home/user` and has the following:

```
DBHOST="localhost"
DBUSER="mysqluser" #MySQL user that can dump all databases
DBPASSWORD="somepasswordwith!and$and+andotherspecialcaracters'"
DBPORT="3306"
```

and the issue is when the password has all the characters possible. How can I escape the `$DBPASSWORD` in this case? The issue is that the command is inside backticks. I have no experience in bash scripts but I've tried with `"$DBPASSWORD"` and with `'$DBPASSWORD'` and it doesn't work.

LATER EDIT:
see the link of the script here, line 170
https://github.com/Ardakilic/backmeup/blob/master/backmeup.sh

Comment: What error message do you get when using `"$DBPASSWORD"`? (Or, if no error message, what information do you get about the failure?)

Comment: when I type in just the password it self in bash I get "event not found" but in this line of mysql I am getting "access denied for user ..."

Comment: It would help if you could also clarify how it fails. On my tests, using double quotes makes it fail because MySQL doesn't recognize the password, for example.

Comment: @terdon Sorry, you are correct I took a call during my reply and just lost track! @Morpheus_ro when *you just type password* are you doing this `backmeup -dbpass 'abc!edf'` or `backmeup -dbpass abc!edf` The 2nd one fails with "can't find event" which is obvious, it's trying to find `edf` in history.